# Complex mysql query. Return as multiple rows as apposed to single row

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following SQL query wich retrieves a record from a table and also it's parents and grandparent. The only issue I have is that it's returned as a single record. I would like it return as multiple rows, as it's stored in the database.

Current structure:

```
comment_id | parent_comment_id
    1              3
    2              7
    3              5
    7              11
```

SQL:

```
SELECT p3.comment_id as `Grandparent`, p2.comment_id as `Parent`, p1.comment_id as `Child`
FROM comments p1
LEFT JOIN comments p2 on p1.comment_id = p2.parent_comment_id
LEFT JOIN comments p3 on p2.parent_comment_id = p3.comment_id
WHERE p1.comment_id = 1
```

Current Output (single row):

```
Grandparent | Parent | Child  
     5          3        1
```

Desired Output (separate rows):

```
comment_id
     5
     3
     1
```

I am editing some existing `mysql` code, I do not have the option to convert everything to `mysqli` or `pdo` at the moment.

Comment: you can use union to generate the multiple row result, if you really want it.

Comment: @Tim3880 I thought UNION can only be used with 2 separate SELECT statements? I'm not sure it can be used in this instance with LEFT JOINS etc.

Comment: **Hint:** You have 3 columns in your `select` clause, but you want only 1 column in your output. Think, how you can resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select comment_id from cm where comment_id = 1
union 
select parent_comment_id from cm where comment_id =1
union
select g.parent_comment_id from cm g
join cm p
on p.parent_comment_id = g.comment_id
where p.comment_id = 1;
```

please verify the logic and make sure it gives you the correct result.

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0dcd/1)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle demo.

Comment: Thanks, i've been working on your example trying to get it to work correctly. I am using a mysql `IN()` function and it's returning the same record twice in some instances. I tried doing a `GROUP BY` but that isn't working as I'm also using a `ORDER BY`

Comment: please show your code. Or better, make it to the SQLFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0dcd/1